# remove duplicates in a string using nested while loop

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to use classical nested while loop to remove the duplicates, but if two of the same characters are present in the middle of a string (not in first and last index) then it is not removing the duplicate.

```
def removeduplicates(String):
    result = ''
    list_of_char = []
    for i in String:
        list_of_char.append(i)
    k = 1
    l = 1
    a = 0
    b = 1
    print(len(list_of_char))
    while k < len(list_of_char):
        while l < len(list_of_char):
            if list_of_char[a].lower() == list_of_char[b].lower():
                del list_of_char[b]
            else:
                pass
            b = b + 1
            l = l + 1
            k = k + 1

    for j in list_of_char:
        result = result + j

    return result


print(removeduplicates('Arpitr'))
```

Expected: `Arpit`

Comment: Do you really need to use loops like that, or can you use set?

Comment: I was wandering if I could use the nested while loops to solve it. So I would like to know if it is possible to solve it via nested while loops.

Comment: You never increment `a`. You have `k`, `l`. Why do you have `a` and `b`?

Comment: I actually have incremented a in my code, I kind of missed it while posting the code here. It still doesn't work. k,l is for looping counters, while a and b is for comparing index position.

Comment: Post your actual code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OrderedDict` can do something like that:

```
import collections
print(''.join(collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys('Arpitr')))
```

Test: https://ideone.com/8lCPec

However if you explicitly want a fix for your code (and also with `lower()`),

```
def removeduplicates(String):
    result = ''
    list_of_char = []
    for i in String:
        list_of_char.append(i)
    k = 0
    print(len(list_of_char))
    while k < len(list_of_char)-1:
        l = k + 1
        while l < len(list_of_char):
            if list_of_char[k].lower() == list_of_char[l].lower():
                del list_of_char[l]
            else:
                l = l + 1
        k = k + 1

    for j in list_of_char:
        result = result + j

    return result


print(removeduplicates('Arpraprapiiiiraptr'))
```

Test here: https://ideone.com/BxGBhR

The two main things:

- characters have to be tested starting from the next character to the current one, meaning `l` (or perhaps `b`) has to be reset inside the outer loop
- when a character is deleted, its position has to be checked again, so the index is not increased.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do :

```
def removeduplicates(string):
    output = ""

    for x in string:
        if x not in output:
            output += x

    return output

print(removeduplicates('Arpitr'))
```

**Output**

> 'Arpit'

Comment: Hello Sebastian,
But this doesnot check the case of the character. I want my code to consider both lower and uppper case characters to be same. Example = if A and a are present in string it should remove an 'a'.